# Multiple user use same token in Laravel/JWT. How to avoid it?

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am new to JWT. I have created a token for one user. But other users can also use the same token, it's not validating. So how to create token based on the user?

```
$user_data = "user details";//EG: my id => 23
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user_data);
```

And also I have checked the token using the following line

```
$check_auth = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
```

Comment: How did you relate user and token in DB?

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks for your reply. Now I am not storing the token in the database. Now I find the solution. I have printed the **$check_auth**. Here I got the user data. Then I have checked the user details based on the user data.

Comment: You need to be sure that 1 auth token is related to exact 1 user. For example, I would dod that on user registration. For having that working, you would need to extend one more field in users table (simplier way) or make another table for tokens if there would be much more complex business plan what various type of tokens could/should do. Then when you have token related directly to user you can grab exact user's data by token and not worry would it take another user.